# Calculate $\prod\limits_{k=0}^\infty{\left( 1-\frac{1}{2^{2^{k}}} \right)}$

Tags: limits, products

Calculate the limit
$$
\lim\limits_{ n \to \infty }\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n}{\left( 1-\frac{1}{2^{2^{k}}} \right)}.
$$

It's bounded and monotonically, so I know it has the limit. But I can't get it.
I used the wolfram and I got 0.350184……

The question for me is whether it have the specific num or something I neglect.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The similar limit with plus instead of minus does indeed have a nice closed form. Not sure about this one, though.

Comment: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cprod%5Climits_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty%7B%5Cleft(%201-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5E%7B2%5E%7Bk%7D%7D%7D%20%5Cright)%7D%24&p=1 gives many posts about the variant mentionned by @IvanNeretin, but none about yours.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. @AnneBauval